# Please help me with this traversing query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

```
CatID  parID  catName
1      -1        A
2       1        B  
3       2        C
4       3        D
```

I want to write a query which returns the parent child relationship in string format.

In the above table the catName has parentId -1, which  means it has got no parent.  B has parentID 1, which means that A is its parent.

So finaly the string is like this

```
A=>B=>c=>D
```

This is the way I want to generate a query.

I'll pass CatID, and it will traverse until it gets a -1.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?  Or straight ADO.NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @CatID int;
set @CatID = 4;

with C as
(
  select parID,
         cast(catName as varchar(max)) as catName
  from YourTable
  where CatID = @CatID
  union all
  select T.parID,
         T.catName + '=>' + C.catName
  from YourTable as T
    inner join C
      on T.CatID = C.parID
)
select catName
from C
where parID = -1
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/70551/traversing-query)

Answer (score 1):

As a partial answer, it sounds like you need a recursive query. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709397/recursive-function-in-sql-server-2005) is a StackOverflow thread with some good information on recursive queries. As to how to use a query to turn it into a single string, I don't know... that part may be more optimized for a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

you need to define function then call it in recursive loop.

You can use [MPTT (Modified Preorder Tree Traversal)](http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/mptt-modified-preorder-tree-traversal-php-tree-menu-script-t5713.html) to store nested tree or hierarchical data.

[this article](http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/breadcrum-modified-pre-order-tree-transversal-mptt-sql-query-t5865.html) describe how to get hierarchical "breadcrumb" within a single query.