# Create a recursive stored procedure in T-SQL to calculate the n-th Fibonacci number

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

i have given the following question in assignment. i m not able to understand how to pass argument in stored procedure. 
Quesiton :

`If n = 1, FibNum(a, b, n) = a`
 `If n = 2, FibNum(a, b, n) = b` 
`If n > 2, FibNum(a, b, n) = FibNum(a, b, n-1) + FibNum(a, b, n-2) a`.

Create a **recursive stored procedure FibNum in T-SQL** to calculate the n-th Fibonacci number, given the following procedure declaration **CREATE PROC FibNum (@a int, @b int, @n int)** where its exit code is the n-th Fibonacci number. 
b. Utilize the stored procedure to calculate the result of FibNum(1, 1, 10).  Attach the screenshot.

Comment: homework? If so, please identify it as such. This answer will do you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1709414/467473

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursive function in sql server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709397/recursive-function-in-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procedure

```
create proc FibNum ( @a int, @b int, @n int )
as begin
  if @n = 1 return @a
  if @n = 2 return @b
  if @n > 2 begin
    declare @n1 int = @n - 1, @n2 int = @n - 2, @R1 int, @R2 int
    exec @R1 = FibNum @a,@b,@n1
    exec @R2 = FibNum @a,@b,@n2
    return @R1 + @R2
  end
  return 1
end
```

Utilization :

```
declare @R int
exec @R =  FibNum 1,1,10
select @R
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a function problem, but not because of a recursive stored procedure.  You can actually do this using a recursive CTE.

The natural way of doing this would be something like:

```
with fib as (
      select 1 as i, 0 as n
      union all
      select 2 as i, 1 as n
      union all
      select f1.i + 1, f1.n + f2.n2
      from fib f1 join
           fib f2
      where i < 10
     )
select *
from fib;
```

But you can't do this because you can't reference the CTE twice in the `from` clause.

Instead, you want to put the two previous values on a single row:

```
with fib as (
      select 1 as i, 1 as n, 0 as n1
      union all
      select f.i + 1, f.n + f.n1, f.n
      from fib f
      where i < 10
     )
select *
from fib;
```

If you want the nth one, then just change the `10` to the number you want and use `select top 1` with an `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

can't see the need for @a and @b, a recursive fib(n) is achievable with just parameter n

```
CREATE PROC FibNum (@n INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @nminus1 INT, @nminus2 INT, @f1 INT, @f2 INT
    IF @n < 2
        RETURN @n
    ELSE
        SET @nminus1 = @n - 1 
        SET @nminus2 = @n - 2
        EXEC @f1 = FibNum @nminus1
        EXEC @f2 = FibNum @nminus2
        RETURN @f1 + @f2
END
```

Comment: Variables @a and @b are seeds.
And read the question
"given the following procedure declaration CREATE PROC FibNum (@a int, @b int, @n int)"

Answer (score 0):

I had to write this for an assignment, and thought I could post it here.

```
DECLARE @F0 BIGINT = 0
DECLARE @F1 BIGINT = 1
DECLARE @COUNTER BIGINT = 0
DECLARE @INTERIM BIGINT

WHILE @COUNTER < 1000

BEGIN 
    IF @F0 = 0  AND @F1 = 1
        BEGIN
            SELECT @F0 AS 'Fibo' INTO #fibonacci
            INSERT INTO #fibonacci SELECT @F1
            INSERT INTO #fibonacci SELECT @F0 + @F1
            SET @INTERIM = @F0 + @F1
            SET @F0 = @F1
            SET @F1 = @INTERIM
            SET @COUNTER += 1
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #fibonacci SELECT @F0 + @F1
            SET @INTERIM = @F0 + @F1
            SET @F0 = @F1
            SET @F1 = @INTERIM
            SET @COUNTER += 1
        END
END
SELECT * FROM #fibonacci
```